# Access all filenames of pictures in the gallery Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Is there a way to get all the gallery images in Corona SDK? I am aware of the `media` "class", and it's `show()` function, but i intend to add my own functionality, after i found a way to access these image files. I only want to use them in a read-only context, i don't want to modify or delete them. I simply need a function, which will enable this:

```
local galleryFiles = SOME_MAGIC_FUNCTION_HERE();

for i=1, #galleryFiles do
    local fileName = galleryFiles[i];
    local image = display.newImage(fileName);
end
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: So there is no other way to access gallery files, than using the media class?

Comment: AFAIK, no! one thing you can do.. you can get a Corona enterprise  license(which would probably cost a hell of a lot) and write your own plugin for that, or you can wait for Corona Labs to allow Pro/indie developers to write extensions(which can take forever)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corona does not work well with the gallery at all.

You need to wait for support (something that I think is not even on the roadmap) or buy the enterprise license, that allow you to write native code along Corona (but does NOT give access to Corona source).

The enterprise license I heard is around 1500 USD for a seat... So kinda expensive (specially when you cannot see the source).

Comment: Thank you, that's really sad. What do you think, is it a good workaround, if i try to list those files using the file system (lfs module)? Would it be safe to look up the iPhone, and Android gallery path, and get the files from those directories?

Comment: Corona cannot do that unfortunately, it can only read files in its own sandbox.

Comment: Note that this is related to Apple and Google rules (you cannot easily read files outside your sandbox, the rules are quite complex, so Corona cannot expect to support them both easily)